# crontab at reboot for EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, cron

I'm trying to mount an EBS volume after restart. It does not work.

I set the mount after reboot, in the following manner:

`echo "@reboot 'sudo mount $DEVICE_PATH $TARGET_PATH -O noatime,noexec'" | sudo tee -a /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`

It used to work in the past (as best as I can remember). Now it does nothing.
I also tried the following to test if the cron runs (and it does not):

`echo "@reboot 'touch /home/ubuntu/a.txt'" | sudo tee -a /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`

Yes, I know that I could just put this in `/etc/fstab`, but I don't want to do this, as I want the instance to successfully load, even if the volume is detached (otherwise it gets stuck, and you can't ssh to fix things).

I also checked with `ps aux | grep cron` and cron daemon is running:

```
root       877  0.0  0.0  19112   888 ?        Ss   07:46   0:00 cron
```